# Getting : No module named 'clr' after changing python version

Tags: python

I had python 3.7.7 32bit installed on my laptop. I installed pip and pythonnet.

I have this line of code in my python project which is executing fine.

```
import sys, os, clr, time
from pathlib import Path
```

Now I have installed python 3.7.7 64bit version on my laptop. Before running the application, I changed the current python environment to point to 64bit. Upon changing the env, I'm getting the error :

> No module named 'clr'

Do I have install pythonnet again for 64bit. If yes, how to do it again? Because when I try to install again it says

> Requirement already satisfied: pythonnet in
> c:\users\XXXXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
> (2.5.2) Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in
> c:\users\XXXXXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
> (from pythonnet) (2.21)

It is referring to python37-32 still. How do I target it to python37 (64bit).

Comment: try to uninstall and install again.

Comment: Debug with `python --version`. You may need to specify which python you're using. Your `pip` may be tied to the wrong python as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled into this issue a lot with my classmates in programming classes. The problem is that different programs point to different versions of Python. Assuming you're using VS Code, you are able to change which Python version to use, by the "Python: Select Interpreter" command.
Assuming you're using the terminal, you can change which Python version to use when you type "python", by changing your PATH environments.

Comment: A VERY common problem is to be running `pip` from one Python version, but then running your code from the other one.  This is especially easy to have happen if you're using an IDE, like VS Code, so this answer is totally on the right track.

Comment: Yup, I have experienced before where my classmate's "python" (in the terminal) points to one python version and "pip" points to another python version. When they try to install a package, it says it was installed, but it's not installed in the same directory as "python" is in.